# Convert nodejs-style export to typescript-style export

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

So, in Node.js to export primary and "secondary" functions I would do:

```js
module.exports = (amount) => {
  return amount
}

module.exports.calc = (amount) => {
  return amount * amount
}

module.exports.stringify = (amount) => {
  return String(amount)
}
```

And then call it from other files like so:

```js
const amountix = require('./amountix')

amountix(20) // 20
amountix.calc(20) // 400
amountix.stringify(20) // "20"
```

But now I need to convert the this module from Node.js to TypeScript. I tried the following:

```js
export default (amount: number): number => {
  return amount;
}

export function calc(amount: number): number {
  return amount * amount;
}

export function stringify(amount: number): string {
  return String(amount);
}
```

```js
import * as amountix from "./amountix.ts"

amountix(20) // ERROR: This expression is not callable.
amountix.calc(20) // 400
amountix.stringify(20) // "20"
```

But it gives me error when I call the "primary" function.

How do I do it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as amountix from './amountix';

// call the default method
amountix.default(20);
```

Or

```
import amountix, { calc, stringify } from './amountix';

amountix(20);
```